# Handling jQuery AJAX failures with statusCode

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to globally detect and react to a certain statusCode, using jQuery's statusCode function. However, when a specific call fails, it seems be hitting both the original error and THEN the statusCode. Why is this happening? Can it just hit the statusCode first?

Here is my ajaxSetup:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    statusCode: {
            412 : function(data) {
               alert('do something!');
            }
     }
});
```

And here is a sample instance:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET", 
     url: 'a_url.json', 
     dataType: 'json',
     data : {
          'id': dnaRefTOID
     },
     success: function(data) {
          alert('success');
     },
     error : function(xhr, status, error) {
           alert(xhr.statusText);
     }
 });
```

What I'm seeing is that the call is hitting 'error' before hitting statusCode. I want it to hit statusCode and statusCode always. This example is obviously spread across many ajax calls, so I don't want to use an if statement in each error or else it defeats the point of using statusCode.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can't achieve that without changing jQuery itself.
You could do something like this:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
   if (jqxhr.status == 412) {
      //handle status code 412 here
   }
});
```